# Define $T: P_1 \to P_1$ by $T(a+bx) = (a-b) + ax$. Show that $T$ has an inverse and find the action of $T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Define $T: P_1 \to P_1$ by $T(a+bx) = (a-b) + ax$. Show that $T$ has an inverse and find the action of $T^{-1}$

I have the solution to this question, but I don't quite understand a part of it.

The solution is:

> $T(1) = 1+x$
>
> $T(x) = -1$
>
> This shows that $T$ carries the basis $B=\{1, x\}$ to the basis $D=\{1+x, -1\}$ and hence, $T$ is an isomorphism. $T^{-1}$ carries $D$ back to $B$, that is,
>
> $T^{-1}(1+x)=1$
>
> $T^{-1}(-1)=x$
>
> Because $a+bx = b(1+x)+(b-a)(-1)$
>
> we get $T^{-1}(a+bx)=...=b+(b-a)x$

I don't understand how they came up with the right-hand side of the equation:

$a+bx = b(1+x)+(b-a)(-1)$

Comment: Write a matrix of T from $T(1) = 1\cdot1 + 1\cdot x, T(x) = -1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x$. Then finding the inverse of a two by two matrix becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way to find the inverse of $T.$ you have $$T(x) = -1, T(1) = 1+x. $$ that is $$T^{-1}(-1)=x, T^{-1}(1+x) = 1.$$ use the linearity of $T, T^{-1}$ to get $$T^{-1}(1) = -x, T^{-1}(x) = 1 - T^{-1}(1) = 1 + x , \\T^{-1}(a+bx) = aT^{-1}(1)  + bT^{-1}(x)= -ax + b(1+x)=b+(b-a)x.$$